# PySide6 QTabView - Search in a QTabView the index of a tab knowing its objectname

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6

I state that I did some research, but I don't know why the results always concern the QTableView and not the QTabView!!
That said, I was wondering if it's possible, but I haven't found any other way, to get the index of a tab of a QTabView without having to cycle through them all!!
Here is the code I used....

```
# tabStagione :QTabView
# search the tab "tabRegistro"
index :int = 0
    for x in range(tabStagione.count()):
        if tabStagione.widget(x).objectName() == "tabRegistro":
            index = x
            break
# rename the tab in question
tabStagione.setTabText(index, "REGISTRO " + stagione)
```

I didn't find a property like QTabView.widget.getName()

Comment: There is no such thing as a `QTabView`. There is a `QTabBar`, and a `QTabWidget`. That would explain your search results. From your code it looks like you're using a TabWidget, and no, it isn't possible to get a tab index from its widgets object name directly. You have to do what you're currently doing.

Comment: I assume that you created the UI in Designer (otherwise you'd know that there's no such thing as QTabView, and that's a QTabWidget), so you're using the pyuic class or the `uic` module functions, then you don't need any of that: it's just `self.tabRegistro` (or `self.ui.tabRegistro` if you used composition), and you can get its index using [`indexOf()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#indexOf). Note that using the same `tab` prefix for names that refer to *different* types of widgets (the QTabWidget itself and its "pages") is not a very good choice: names should always hint about their types.

Comment: Ok I made a little confusion, I apologize and thank you for your cooperation.
We are talking about a QTabWidget named "tabStagione" which has a tab named "tabRegistro".

I can't find the index with:
'index = tabStagione.indexOf(tabRegistro)'
because tabRegistro doesn't recognize me as a widget but it's practically unknown, I think this is because these parameters are passed to the function where the code is located:
'def start(stagione :str, tabStagione :QTabWidget, tblStagione :QTableView):'

Comment: not even like this: index = tabStagione.indexOf(tabStagione.tabRegistro)